# How to remove boundaries in matplotlib rectangles?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following snippet draws non-overlapping rectangles and works as expected:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect=1)
    
for i in range(5, 30, 5):
    for j in range(5, 30, 5):
        rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((i, j), 5, 5, color='blue')
        ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.xlim([0, 45])
plt.ylim([0, 45])
plt.show()
```

[image]

But when I wish to make the rectangles transparent, they tend to have a border around them, as shown below:

```py
        rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((i, j), 5, 5, color='blue', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Initially, I thought maybe that was due to some overlaps. So, I reduced the size of the rectangles, but I still got it.
For example, if I use

```py
        rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((i, j), 4.5, 4.5, color='blue', alpha=0.2)
```

I get the following:

[image]

A zoomed-in version of the above image is:

[image]

As you can see, I still get those boundaries with lower transparency (than alpha=0.2). How can I get rid of those boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help

```
rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((i, j), 5, 5, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.2,edgecolor = None)
```